# .htaccess equivalent rules?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

To prevent access from other sites (hotlinking) or direct access (typing an URL) are the .htaccess rules below equivalents?

### RULE 1

```
<files myfile_one.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

<files myfile_two.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

### RULE 2

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^myfile_(one|two).php$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Your first rule simply blocks all access to the named files, doesn't that make the second completely redundant?

Comment: That was my question, HBruijn. If they are the same (equivalents). Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

I think for what you're trying to accomplish, I'd say "yes", but with the caveat if you wanted to be super technical, I think the  directives match those filenames in any folder, but the RewriteRule as written is only in the current folder.  Also, I think  is case-sensitive but your rule is case-insensitive due to [NC].